# Xamarin/iOS/Android - Display other elements when focusing a text field

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a Microsoft Xamarin project using native .xib files for iOS and .axml for Android. When I focus on a text field on the screen and the keyboard is presented, usually the keyboard covers the validation message that is shown beneath the text field.

I want to keep the focus behaviour so I'm hoping there is a way to focus on the text field and include a 'buffer' so other fields can be seen whilst the keyboard is present.

I've discovered that focusing and then scrolling is really janky and not the best user experience. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

#### in iOS , you can use the plugin [Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager)

in your UIViewController

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.EnableAutoToolbar = true;
    Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.ShouldResignOnTouchOutside = true;
    Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.ShouldToolbarUsesTextFieldTintColor = true;
    Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.KeyboardDistanceFromTextField = 300f;           
}
```

#### in Android

You should put the layout in a ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">


  //... your layout
</ScrollView>
```

And set the **windowSoftInputMode** in **Manifest.xml**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```